# What data formats should a RESTful webservice support?

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm thinking of starting with XML, JSON, and [DSON](http://dogeon.org/) (because why not?). Are there other formats that are or should be used?

Comment: Personally I'd never heard of DSON before. While I'd suggest that XML and JSON would cover most possibilities if I really wanted to include every possibility then next on my list would be yaml

Comment: Put that in an answer!

Comment: Depending from the service specificity (which you don't disclose) other formats may be useful. For example, exchange market news are often delivered as CSV.

Comment: You should also put that in an answer! You both answered my question.

Comment: This is far too subjective. You support all you need, and a need all you support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to include hypermedia in your responses then I recommend using one of Mason, HAL, Sirene, Hydra (JSON-LD), Collection+JSON or UBER (all depending on your preferences).

Comment: Most of these are just JSON I think, but with 'conventions' on how you present the data.